# Quicker Iteration in python through a big list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to scan a list of 100,000,000 (list1) strings and match it with another list(list2).
List 1 can have upto 10 million rows.
If the contents of list2 are in list1 I am flagging those values in a counter and storing the result in a third list. So my lists are somewhat like this :

list1

```
['My name is ABC and I live in DEF',
'I am trying XYZ method to speed up my LMN problem'
... 100000 rows
]
```

list2 ( length 90k )

```
['ABC','DEF','XYZ','LMN' ......XXX']
```

I have converted list 1 to a dataframe and list 2 to a joined list ( reduce the number of passes ) .
Updated List 2 :

```
['ABC|DEF|XYZ...|XXX']
```

My desired output is :

```
['My name is ABC and I live in DEF',2] ( since I have two matching patterns with list2 )
```

I have tried the below code , but it is taking a lot of time to iterate through the df and give me the result. Can you please let me know how to make this code faster and what exactly am I doing wrong ?

```
import snowflake.connector
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
my_list=[]
df_list1 = pd.DataFrame({'cola':cola_val})
for row in tqdm.tqdm(df_product_list.values):
    val= row[0]
    match_list = re.findall(SKU_LIST,str(val),re.IGNORECASE)
    my_list.append(str(val)+'~'+str(len(set(match_list))))
```

Comment: How many strings are you searching for?  Regular expression searches with alternation aren't particularly quick.  Remember it has to check every character for a match with every alternative.

Comment: @TimRoberts, the OP has noted `list2 ( length 90k )`

Comment: That's never going to be quick.  It might actually be faster to `split` each line of `list1` and do `if word in list2:`.

Comment: yes, regexp is not a good  option here

Comment: list1 can have around a million rows as well , (let me edit my question) , won't splitting every of list1 slow things down ?

Comment: I Used your answer and it worked like a charm .One follow up question though , my string can have multiple delimiters using which I may want to split , will the above logic hold good there as well. For example if my string has "ABC+DEF+XYZ I am trying this : MNH" and the set is ['ABC','DEF','XYZ','MNH'] , the above code will not yield the correct result right ? @RomanPerekhrest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case regexp is not a good option as it's quite costly and the alternation `(..|..| 90K items)` will cause a huge regex backtracking. 
Convert your `lst2` into a `set` object beforehand and find intersection to each splitted sentence:

```
def count_keys_within(lst1, lst2):
    keys = set(lst2)
    for s in lst1:
        yield [s, len(set(s.split()) & keys)]

counts = list(count_keys_within(lst1, lst2))
print(counts)
```

---

Sample output:

```
[['My name is ABC and I live in DEF', 2], ['I am trying XYZ method to speed up my LMN problem', 2]]
```

---

**Update:**
If sentences have more complex delimiters (you mentioned `+`) use a precompiled regex pattern for splitting which can be extended with other additional delimiter chars:

```
def count_keys_within(lst1, lst2):
    keys = set(lst2)
    pat = re.compile(r'[\s+]')
    for s in lst1:
        yield [s, len(set(pat.split(s)) & keys)]
```

Comment: I Used this and it worked like a charm .One follow up question though , my string can have multiple delimiters using which I may want to split , will the above logic hold good there as well. For example if my string has "ABC+DEF+XYZ I am trying this : MNH" and the set is ['ABC','DEF','XYZ','MNH'] , the above code will not yield the correct result right ? @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: @AritraBhattacharya, use my update

Comment: I used your update and tweaked it a bit. Included a few more delimiters and cases. This was great. I always have a habit to going to regex for pattern matching -;) . This solution was simple and yet very effective. Thanks.